# Как передать массив в input value?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть функция JS, возвращающая массив строк :

```
function retCity(){
    let url = <?php echo json_encode($cit) ?>;
    let res = JSON.parse(url);
    let cityArr = new Array() ;
    cityArr = res.name ;
    let arr = [] ;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < res.length ; i++){
        arr[i] = res[i].name ;
    }
    return arr ;
}
```

И есть форма , которая передаёт значение input на другую страницу :

```
<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="varnamе" value="место для массива">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Как присвоить value значение массива,а после все эти данные передать на другую страницу ?

Comment: Зачем его передавать дальше? Если его "дальше" можно брать так же, как и берёте сейчас. Почему get? И почему input не скрытый с массивом?

Comment: потому что в другом файле php он передаётся в переменную ,а там уже значение этой переменной используется по-своему

Comment: Что мешает там его брать?

Comment: Как оказалось , передать функцию jS переменной PHP мне не так уж легко,поэтому ищу обходные пути)

Comment: Смотрите. У вас, условно, index страница, вы с неё хотите передать значение ($cit) на test, при этом, эти данные никак не изменяются. Какой в этом смысл если можно на  test странице брать те же данные ($cit)?

Comment: а тут уже другой вопрос вылазит : парсирование XML , и тут уже масса ошибок вылазит , не понятных мне

Comment: Если Вы игнорируете все предложения InDevX, то что Вам мешает присвоить скрытому input id и устанавливать его value при загрузке страницы? И даже в этом случае лучше на стороне сервера создавать массив и ваводить его в value без использования js `<input type="hidden" name="varnamе" value="<?php echo $cityArr; ?>">`. P.S.: что Вы имели ввиду создавая новый массив cityArr и перезаписывая его строкой на следующем шаге и это при том, что Вы его больше нигде не используете.